# Drag Text from an item of QListWidget to QLabel

Tags: c++, qt

I'm looking for the simpliest way, using Qt Designer and a little code, to drag text from a QListWidget (apparently there are options of draggable content in Qt Designer) to a QLabel (but I can't find any droppable action option ...) so its text is set to the text of the item we dragged.
Any ideas ?

[C++, Windows, Qt5]

Answer (score 1):

Well, yeah, the most straightforward idea is subclassing QLabel and reimplementing it's

`void dropEvent(QDropEvent* event)`

**QDrag** object will help you pass text from QListWidget via it's mimeData, just create one in mouse event handler.

Check [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20002566/how-to-implement-drag-n-dropping-widget-to-another-container-in-qt) questions or [examples](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/examples-draganddrop.html) for more information.